# Managed Metadata and Word 2007

Tags: word

Are Managed Metadata fields supported in the Word 2007 Document Information Panel? We are having an issue with a client where they are opening a word document in SharePoint 2010 with Word 2007 and for the Managed Metadata fields they are read only with the text saying "Edit Property on Server"

Can anyone provide some insight or a solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope seems like its not, so its time to upgrade people!!!